# Check windows update file integrity

Tags: windows, updates

I have to update frequently offline windows systems.

So i download the update file (KB) on windows website and run the file on the systems.

I would like to know if there is a recommended way to check the integrity of a windows update file (kb).
My purpose is to be sure that the file is correct and has not been modified in a way or another before applying it.

So i need something like an official MD5 signature as reference value to compare with the signature of the downloaded file, but i can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All Windows Update files (.exe, .msi, .msu, .cab) are signed using Authenticode – the data hash together with a digital signature are embedded into the file so Windows can verify it on its own.

- Through PowerShell:

  ```
  Get-AuthenticodeSignature foo.cab | Format-List
  ```
- Through Cmd (only if you have the [Windows 10 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869552/how-to-install-signtool-exe-for-windows-10) installed):

  ```
  signtool verify /v /pa foo.msi
  ```
- Through GUI:

  1. Right-click the file, select "Properties" → "Digital Signatures".
  2. Select a signature from the list and click "Details".

In all three cases, make sure the signature is valid and comes from "Microsoft Code Signing PCA" (chaining to Microsoft Root Certificate Authority).

*Note that MD5 or SHA1 hashes on their own aren't signatures. A signature is created by combination of a hash and a secret key (such as Authenticode signing certificate).*

Comment: Thanks' for your answer.
My knowledge in cryptography is quite limited, and i'm used to limit myself to SHA1/MD5 hash.
Do you see any problems/limitations to use Суомынона method which is more usual for me ?

Comment: @S.Brottes See my comment to their answer

Answer (score 5):

If you downloaded the update files through Microsoft Update Catalog:

[image]

You will see SHA1 of the MSU package present in its file name:

[image]

The string highlighted in blue is its SHA-1 ([Secure Hash Algorithm-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)) value, which is always 40 characters long, this value will be changed if the file content is modified.

You can use this method to check if the file is authentic, you can use PowerShell to do this;

First, to open PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `PowerShell`>><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then you need the full path of your file and filename, in this example, the file is downloaded to the default downloads folder, which is `C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads` folder, in PowerShell you can use this variable: `$home` to represent `C:\Users\Username` (your user profile) folder.

You can use `Get-Filehash` cmdlet to get the hash of the file and check it against the hash in its filename by using `-eq` operator, if the result is `true` then the file is good. If it returns `false` then the file is corrupted.

I will give you this example to describe the method better:

```powershell
(get-filehash -path "$home\downloads\windows10.0-kb4592438-x86_95758bd6e2c3a4a98a19efaa4056213531f84f5c.msu" -algorithm SHA1).hash -eq "windows10.0-kb4592438-x86_95758bd6e2c3a4a98a19efaa4056213531f84f5c.msu".split("_")[1].substring(0,40)
```

It returns `true`, means my file isn't corrupted.

When you use it, just replace the file name and file path with the real name and path of the file you want to check. And then you are good to go.

Comment: This method doesn't check the authenticity of a file, just its integrity. If you want to just check if the file was downloaded correctly, it's fine. But if you want to ensure it's a legit file from Microsoft, forging an update that will pass this check is trivial.

Comment: Well comrade, did you read the question's title? The original poster explicitly stated that they want to check the integrity of the file, and my answer does exactly that.

Comment: And, well, I specifically stated in my answer "through Microsoft Update Catalog", I think that would be anthentic enough. I fail to see how the website can be a fake one.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is bad - just that your method is sufficient for some use cases, but not for the others. I've posted this comment mostly as a response to OP asking about weaknesses of this method in a comment elsewhere. I've read the question title, but some visitors may come here later googling a completely different solution and not notice that this approach is insecure _for their use case_. Hence I think a little comment pointing out a weakness of this method, while saying what it's good for, adds some value.

Answer (score 3):

Суомынона's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1618921) is correct, I just want to add that you can wrap the code in a function:

```powershell
function Check-Update {
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Valuefrompipeline=$True)] [Validatenotnullorempty()] [String]$Path 
)
$IsGood=$false

if ($(Test-Path $Path) -and $Path.EndsWith(".msu")) {
    $SHA1 = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path).Split("_")[1]
    $Hash = (Get-FileHash -Path $path -Algorithm SHA1).Hash
    $IsGood=$($SHA1 -eq $Hash)
    Switch ($IsGood)
    {
        $true {Write-Host "Your update file: $path is NOT corrupted"}
        $false {Write-Host "Your update file: $path IS corrupted"}
    }
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Update file: $path doesn't exist as a valid update file"
    }
}
```

Paste the function into a working PowerShell session, and then you can check integrity of an update file by calling the function, e.g.:

```powershell
Check-Update "$home\downloads\windows10.0-kb4592438-x86_95758bd6e2c3a4a98a19efaa4056213531f84f5c.msu"
```

If everything is alright it will return:

```powershell
Your update file: C:\Users\Estranger\downloads\windows10.0-kb4592438-x86_95758bd6e2c3a4a98a19efaa4056213531f84f5c.msu is NOT corrupted
```

I hope my answer helps you; Regards.